# GNU watch - how do I make it read my environment (aliases, functions, etc)

Tags: linux, gnu, watch, env

This one has been bugging me for a while: I want to use the marvelous GNU `watch` command to run a few custom aliases and functions that are defined in my .bashrc, but it is never able to run anything except bash built-ins or binaries.

`watch -d foo`

The output is always: `foo: command not found`

How can I make it inherit my environment or use the .bashrc?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `foo`? A shell script? An alias? What if you run that `watch` command from your prompt?

Comment: As I mentioned, `foo` can be a custom alias or a bash function, not just a simple call to a binary.

Comment: Here's an example of a bash function:

`x () { xmllint -format $* ;}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do something like this `watch bash -i -c 'alias -p'` this should call bash, load your settings and then run whatever command you have after the `-c`

Comment: Brilliant - that worked like a charm.

Comment: Great! But my functions are still not visible :(
....when is used after pipe (|)

Answer (score 1):

From `man watch`:

> Note that command is given to "sh -c"

So it's not going to see your Bash aliases and functions.